# How to duplicate a file a number of times while embedding an index in each file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, file-copy

I have a file named, for example, `ascdrgi.txt`, with the following contents:

```
tiger
lion
cat
```

I want to duplicate this file a (variable) number of times by changing the last character of the filename (ignoring the extension). For example, in this case if I made 3 copies, they would be named:

- `ascdrgj.txt`
- `ascdrgk.txt`
- `ascdrgl.txt`

If the filename ends with a number, that number should increase instead, so copies of `ascdrg1.txt` would be:

- `ascdrg2.txt`
- `ascdrg3.txt`
- `ascdrg4.txt`

If the file already exists, the script should skip that name and move onto the next one. If we reach the last character (`z`, `Z`, or `9`), it should loop around to the beginning (the next would be `a`, `A`, or `1`, respectively).

In addition to duplicating the original file, I need to modify the first line of each file to say which file it is (numerically), as well as the total number of files. Using the first `ascdrgi.txt` example, that file would now contain:

```
tiger number(1,4)
lion
cat
```

The next file, `ascdrgj.txt`, would contain:

```
tiger number(2,4)
lion
cat
```

and so on.

Comment: awk '/^----/{f="file"(++c)".txt"}c{print$0>f}' filename. here i am searching by pattern and dividing the file. but i need the exact file but the last character will be incrementing

Comment: I edited the question to include all the comments and removed them. There was a conflict between what the question said ("If the file already exists, I should get an error saying already exists.") and one of the comments ("if A already exist then it should go for B."). I went with the comment since it was more recent

Comment: Thank You Michael for sorting it Properly. sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: Michael. let me know if you can help me with this script creation. For "already file exist" part it is ok if we skip it also as in my case duplicate file will not be there

Answer (score 2):

The following shell script will perform (most) of what you need.
It will not modify the original file (not add 'number' to it) - only the newly created files.

Hopefully the comments are clear enough.
Using somewhat convoluted `expr` instead of bash's parameter expansion should make it more portable:

```
#!/bin/sh

orig=ascdrg3.txt # start with this file

in=$orig
count=1 #loop variable
max=5   #number of files to create
while test "$count" -le "$max" ; do
    # Remove extension
    base=$(basename "$in" .txt)

    # get the prefix
    prefix=$(expr substr "$base" 1 $((${#base}-1)))

    # get last letter
    last=$(expr substr "$base" ${#base} 1)

    while true ;
    do
        # Advance letter, while the file doesn't exist
        last=$(echo "$last" | tr A-Z B-ZA)
        last=$(echo "$last" | tr a-z b-za)
        last=$(echo "$last" | tr 0-9 1-90)

        # construct new file name
        new="$prefix$last.txt"

        # continue if it doesn't exist
        # (otherwise, advance the last letter and try again)
        test -e "$new" || break

        test "$new" = "$orig" \
            && { echo "error: looped back to original file" >&2 ; exit 1; }
    done


    # Create new file
    cp "$orig" "$new"

    # Modify first line of new file
    sed -i "1s/\$/number($count,$max)/" "$new"

    # Advance counter
    count=$((count+1))

    # loop again
    in=$new
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For the digit case: , if its like ab1.txt and you want ab2.txt and ab3.txt and so on:

```
  for i in `seq 2 3` ; do cp ab1 ab$i.txt ; done
```

You can do a similar thing for the alphabet case.

```
   for i in `echo {d..f}` ; do cp abc.txt ab$i.txt ; done
```

will result in
abd.txt  abe.txt  abf.txt

Comment: Thanks ljas. Is it possible to have a generic one as the file name cannot be predicted.

Comment: This doesn't seem to cover the second part of the question

Comment: this is just a hint , he needs to work on it further

Comment: yes , you can make it generic by examining the file name and decide the range for `seq $start $end` and `echo {$start...$end}`